# multiple inheritance cast in c++

Tags: c++

I have an issue concerning multiple inheritance cast.
I have 3 base classes

```
class ReadFile;
class WriteFile
class SharedObject; // this class is basically a mutex
```

based on those class I build:

```
class ReadWriteFile : public ReadFile, public WriteFile
{ ... };

class ReadWriteSharedFile : public ReadWriteFile , public SharedObject
{ ... };

class ReadFileShared : public ReadFile, public SharedObject
{ ... };
```

at some point of my code, I have a ReadWriteSharedFile pointer that I would like to cast as a pointer to a ReadFileShared

```
ReadFileShared * l_data = dynamic_cast<ReadFileShared * >(m_data); // m_data is a ReadWriteSharedFile
```

it compiles but at execution, the cast "fails" and l_data is NULL

However, what I want to achieve sounds legit to me. Is it? What am I doing wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ReadFileShared` and `ReadWriteSharedFile` are unrelated classes, although they inherit some same base classes. Therefore, you cannot cast a reference/pointer to one to another.

Your functions should probably use interfaces `ReadFile` and `WriteFile`, rather than require a particular implementation of them. That is the main idea behind interfaces. See [C++ Interface Classes - An Introduction](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/233) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

`dynamic_cast<>` is used to upcast the derived class pointer to one of its primarily ascendant classes.
In your case `ReadWriteShared` class is not derived from `ReadFileShared` so `dynamic_cast<>` will return null pointer.